# which function can replace "create_proc_info_entry" in 2.6.32 of Linux kernel?

Tags: kernel, proc

The 2.6.32 kernel don't have the function of "create_proc_info_entry".
Which function can replace it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

from Documentation/filesystems/seq_file.txt we have the following:

> Deprecated create_proc_entry
>
> Note that the above article uses create_proc_entry which was removed in
>   kernel 3.10. Current versions require the following update
>
> ```
> -   entry = create_proc_entry("sequence", 0, NULL);
> -   if (entry)
> -       entry->proc_fops = &ct_file_ops;
> +   entry = proc_create("sequence", 0, NULL, &ct_file_ops);
> ```

see 80e928f7ebb958f4d79d4099d1c5c0a015a23b93 for more information

Answer (score 0):

May be you need something like this:

```
int proc_read(char *page, char **start, off_t off, int count, int *eof, void *data)
{
    return sprintf(page, "Hello World!\n");
}

create_proc_read_entry("proc_test", 0444, NULL, proc_read, NULL);
```